# Is it possible to suppress the output of term_sendkeys()

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

Sometimes there are lots of lines to be sent from the editor to the terminal and therefore thethe latter scroll a lot as soon as it execute the received commands. That may not be too nice to see sometimes.
I wonder if there is any way to suppress the terminal output (or to make it to show only errors) when you send something through the `term_sendkeys()` command.